# Duplicated items in array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm trying to save the records of table called "books" into an array using PHP. book table has some columns which I would like to fetch. Thus I wrote this query:

```
"SELECT b.book_name,b.book_description,b.book_link,c.category_name FROM books b,
    category c WHERE b.category_id  = c.category_id AND b.category_id !=0"
```

I was able to fetch and store data into the array, but you can see a problem when I printed the array as JSON response.

```
{"book_name":"Book 1","0":"Book 1","book_description":"this is the book number 1","1":"this is the book number 1","book_link":null,"2":null,"category_name":"Story","3":"Story"}
```

My question, how to remove these duplicated items("0":"Book 1") from the array?

The complete PHP code:

```
<?php
include("connection.php");


        getAllBooks($cnn);

//Print result as json


function getAllBooks($cnn)
{
    $query = "SELECT b.book_name,b.book_description,b.book_link,c.category_name FROM books b,
    category c WHERE b.category_id  = c.category_id AND b.category_id !=0";
    $stmt = $cnn->prepare($query);

    $stmt->execute();
    $rowcount = $stmt->rowCount();
    $myObj = new stdClass();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
    $books_list = array();
    while($row= $stmt->fetch())
       {
      $myObj2  = $row;
      $books_list[] = $row;
       }

       $myObj -> action_result ="success";
       $myObj -> books_list =$books_list;

   }
else
{
       $myObj -> action_result ="fail";
}

$jsonObj = json_encode($myObj);
echo $jsonObj;

}

?>
```

Comment: array_unique()?

Comment: Use a proper `JOIN` in your query instead of `FROM books b,
    category c`

Comment: @Blackbam: Fetch duplicates and then remove them? Doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: No, but that was my fastest guess. SQL is definitly more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either want to pass the `$fetch_style`, which defaults to value of `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` (which defaults to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`).

> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set.

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Or set it before fetching:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: i would like to understand the reason behind the error?

Comment: It's not an error.  The manual tells you http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` (**default**): returns an array indexed by **both** column name **and** 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set.

Comment: Ahha , super thanx again.